# Does a Python 3 TCP Socket have to be connected in order to send data? Or not like UDP?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp, connection

I want to make a TCP Socket that doesn't connect to the host but instead sends data without connecting... Is that possible with the Python 3 Socket module?

Comment: TCP is always about connecting to other side. If you don't want to explicitly connect use UDP protocol.

Comment: What does "connect" mean to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TCP sockets always need to be connected before sending data. Establishing the connection involves an actual packet exchange with the peer, i.e. the [TCP 3-way handshake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#Connection_establishment). This is also means that the connect can fail if the target cannot be reached. This is not specific to Python but specific to how TCP sockets work.

With UDP a socket can be connected but does not need to be. Connecting a UDP socket essentially just sets the target on the local socket but does not involve any actual data transfer. This also means that the connect will usually not fail even but a later data transfer might not be able to reach the target.